# Move file from Team Drive to Personal Drive using Google Drive API PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to make a script that can move a file from a **Team Drive** to a **Personal Drive**.

I managed to move the file from the `Personal Drive` to the `Team Drive`. But when I want to move the file back to the `Personal Drive` I get this error:

> { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "File not found: 1cI_gUJyVFGF-_U6umbMVJFoRcvzOQoB2.", "locationType": "parameter", "location": "fileId" } ], "code": 404, "message": "File not found: 1cI_gUJyVFGF-_U6umbMVJFoRcvzOQoB2." } }

This is my script:

```
//The file on the Team Drive
$fileId = '1cI_gUJyVFGF-_U6umbMVJFoRcvzOQoB2';
//The folder id from the personal Drive
$folderId = '1uXONHLA7jUUDxvc-puqyHdMOWRSvvSys';
$emptyFileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file = $driveService->files->get($fileId, array('fields' => 'parents'));
$previousParents = join(',', $file->parents);
$file = $driveService->files->update($fileId, $emptyFileMetadata, array(
    'addParents' => $folderId,
    'removeParents' => $previousParents,
    'fields' => 'id, parents',
    'supportsTeamDrives' => 'true',
    ));
```

Comment: Drive API V3 - I am also struggling with a simple requirement to move a file from one folder to another. This should be so simple but isnt, having to use new Google_Service_DriveFile() to do it does not move the metadata. If we use the orig file it give a 'fieldNotWritable' error as it includes obviously some private attributes